# Command prompt not working after installing TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2003

I have just installed that latest stable release of TortoiseSVN on Windows Server 2003 and restarted the server. I can create a new repository using the right-click menu in windows explorer but using "svn" anything from the command prompt returns

'svn' is not a recognised internal or external command

When I have installed TortoiseSVN previously in XP or Vista it has worked fine. What am I missing here?!

**EDIT:**
The specific command I need to run is

svnadmin load repository-name < repository-name.dmp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TortoiseSVN does not install the command line tools for SVN. Did you by any chance also install VisualSVN on your other machine? (which does include the command line tools)

Comment: Yes I did install VisualSVN on the other machines. Is there a standalone installer that will give the command line support? If not will the command line stop working if the VisualSVN 30 day licence expires?

Comment: You can also download directly from the Subversion project, if you don't want to go through Collab.net's registration process: http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100 (don't be turned off by the "Apache 2.2" label, it isn't required if you're just using the command-line stuff)

Comment: @ASk — You are incorrect. I have both TSVN 1.5.x and 1.6.x in front of me, and neither includes the `svn` or `svnadmin` executables. From the folder name, I'm guessing you (or someone else using that computer) simply unzipped the official Subversion build into the TSVN folder.

Comment: @ASk: TortoiseSVN does NOT include the command line tools. Double-checked on 3 machines. Please check facts before voting something down.

Comment: @Ben: registration, eh? Huh, hadn't realized they were pulling that crap. Removed the link, shame 'cause it looked more stable.

Comment: I installed a recent nightly (TortoiseSVN 1.6.99, Build 16452 - 32 Bit -dev, 2009/05/25 19:19:31), and got no Subversion tools installed.

Comment: @Shog9 — Collab.net's page is much clearer and easier to navigate, too. I'm not sure why they thought registration was a good idea. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have installed TortoiseSVN for the GUI based tool. But, I need command like tool for my automated build script where auto check out and build occurs.
I tried **Slik-Subversion-1.7.4-x64** which gave me command prompt access for svn commands.