# Add files to an already setup svn repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, remote-server

I want to add a folder to a remote server with the svn repository set up. In my local computer I have tortoiseSVN. All I want to do is add folder from my local computer to the repo setup in the remote directory? ANy pointers? You can tell I'm not a svn person :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can copy the directory into your checked-out copy of the repository, then right click on the file, go to TortoiseSVN, and select add.  This will add the folder to your repo, then commit the change (right click and select SVN Commit), and you should be good.

If that isn't sufficient for your question, I apologize.

GotAmye,
As long as the remote server is housing a subversion repository, this should work.  What is running on the remote server that makes you think there will be a problem?

Comment: For me that didn't work. They key for me was to open the Repo Browser, change to the remote repo view, and then right click and choose the "Add file" menu item.   This allowed me to add a file to the remote view where I had already added to my local view using the method described above.

Comment: What if I want to add a linux machine to an existing repository?  Rather than a local folder.

Comment: I know this post is old, but I just ran into this. Instead of having to copy the directory to somewhere else, in TortoiseSvn you can "Import in Place":
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html#tsvn-dug-import-in-place

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help everyone. Your pointers were very helpful.
Here is a summary of what I did:

1. From my remote server, I checked out the svn repository on which I wanted to add my folder
2. On the checked out repo (now in my local computer), I added the folders that I wanted.
3. Right click on the newly added folder (on which all the added files are present)->TortoiseSVN->add
4. To commit the changes TortoiseSVN->Commit

Answer (score 2):

```
svn import path URL
```

Recursively commits a copy of path to URL. If path is omitted the current directory is assumed. Parent directories are created as necessary in the repository.

Comment: I was under the impression that TortoiseSVN couldn't be used from the Windows command prompt, is that not true?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you are correct.

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922365/command-prompt-not-working-after-installing-tortoisesvn

Comment: You can download the command-line tools here: 
http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91

Answer (score 1):

Well if the location that you added the folder to on disk is already the working location for part of the repository you can simply right click the folder ->TortoiseSVN->Add

Comment: But the remote server doesn't have TortoiseSVN setup. It's only on my local computer.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is just the client for the subversion server, the server itself doesn't need Tortoise setup.

Comment: Hmm, there is no "add" menu on the TortoiseSVN. I've tried import, export, etc.

Comment: In my experience "Add" just works on the local repository.  Getting the file/files into the remote repository is achieved with a "import" but Tortoise doesn't have this option.  It confuses me too.